# Error during I move a file with System.IO.file.move in console.application(c#), Can you help me?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

My exception came in my try/catch :

```
06/10/2014 16:48:06 - System.IO.IOException: O processo não pode acessar o arquivo porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   em System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   em BMP_txt_to_xml.clsMain.CopiaArquivos() na C:\PROJETOS\GestaoNet.Converter-Icon\Icon\clsMain.cs:linha 785
   em BMP_txt_to_xml.clsMain.CheckEnergiaFiles(String TxtArquivoEntrada, String TxtArquivoSaida, String TxtArquivoCopia, String TxtArquivoLog) na C:\PROJETOS\GestaoNet.Converter-Icon\Icon\clsMain.cs:linha 108
   em BMP_txt_to_xml.clsMain.Start() na C:\PROJETOS\GestaoNet.Converter-Icon\Icon\clsMain.cs:linha 48
   em BMP_txt_to_xml.Program.Main() na C:\PROJETOS\GestaoNet.Converter-Icon\Icon\Program.cs:linha 20
```

I need CURRENT help please, I'm brazilan and my english is terrible, sorry !!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The file is locked.  You can't move it because another process has that lock.  Also, you should check out [pt.so]

Comment: can you please post what your current code looks like where you are calling `System.IO.Move()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file cannot be moved because "it is locked by another process". 
In other words: A different application, or your own application, is currently accessing the file you want to move.